# Limits on number of simultaneous equations solvable with Python's odeint routine

Tags: python, scipy, python-3.4

I am new to Python 3.4 and contemplating using Python to solve a large reaction-diffusion compartment model in cell physiology and am wondering about how many simultaneous first-order ordinary differential equations can be solved using Pythons odeint routine.  My problem will require solving at least 300 first-order ode's simultaneously.  Can odeint do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SciPy's `odeint` it is stated in the doc's that Fortran's odepack is used beneath the hood, which is probably as good as it gets:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Yes you can.